# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xiaomi/mipush/sdk/PushMessageReceiver

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile-development, zegocloud

Issue: When I try to integrate RoboElectric burst into the application, this error occurs, i am trying to resolve this. but still, I can't. I have attached the log error image below.

I have tried multi-dex dependency and enabled it in Gradle but a still error occurs

particularly this error

com/xiaomi/mipush/sdk/PushMessageReceiver

I am using Zegocloud for a chat where I am receiving data & responses from them, I have commented out Zegocloud code all over the application  robot electric burst is working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtPaJ.png)

My question is Without commenting on the Zegocloud code I need to solve this any solution from you will help me to solve this. Thanks in advance :)